# Is it possible to monitor particular already known email account?

Tags: android, android-intent

If i know the email account, for example `abc.xyz@pqr.com`, can I monitor the email attachment downloads of a this particular account. 
Other Requirements

1. I want the location of the downloaded attachment so that I can control the downloaded things.
2. Control in the sense encryption of downloaded file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible?

If you write your own email client that does the downloading of the attachments, yes. Or, if you find some email client that offers an API for this, then yes. Generally speaking, though, this is not possible.